# A Subversion guide for a Git user?

Tags: git, svn, version-control

I seem to belong to a particular category of developers that have never worked with any SCM other than Git. This poses a problem because now I need to find my way around an SVN repo. There are numerous guides to help SVN developers migrate to Git, but I have been having a lot of trouble finding one tailored for Git users. Unfortunately, the search terms I can think of don't distinguish between the two.

Are there any guides to Subversion from the perspective of a Git user?

---

Note: I'll obviously look over those SVN -> Git, and pure SVN guides as they're useful, but I'm still curious to see if something that matches my specific criteria exists. If it does, I'll likely be able to relate to the concepts presented much more easily.

Comment: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm still curious to see if something that matches my specific criteria exists

it **doesn't exist** due to obvious reason - it's just useless wasted time (for writer of such guide)

Answer (score 2):

It's not really a guide to svn, but [git-svn](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html) is an adapter that allows you to use git wtih svn repositories. Note that it may not work with some svn repositories, you'll have to try and see if it works for you. You get a lot of the benefits of git (you can do work locally without talking to the server).